# How to debug flex(lexer) file? `warning, -s option given but default rule can be matched`

Tags: flex-lexer

```
warning, -s option given but default rule can be matched
```

I got the above warning when I use the following flex file. I don't know how to debug the rule. Could anybody show me the easiest way to figure out what is wrong?

```
%option nodefault
%x STRING

%%

  const char fmt[] = "%s\t%s\t%s\n";

<INITIAL>\"       {
  BEGIN(STRING);
  fprintf(yyout, fmt, "<INITIAL>\\\"", yytext, "");
}

<INITIAL>[^"\n]     {
  fprintf(yyout, fmt, "<INITIAL>[^\"\\n]", yytext, yytext);
}

<INITIAL>\n       {
  fprintf(yyout, fmt, "<INITIAL>\\n", "\\n", "");
}

<STRING>\\[\\"]   {
  fprintf(yyout, fmt, "<STRING>\\\"", yytext, yytext+1);
}

<STRING>\n        {
  fprintf(yyout, fmt, "<STRING>", "\\n", "\\n");
}

<STRING>\"        {
  fprintf(yyout, fmt, "<STRING>\\\"", yytext, "");
  BEGIN(INITIAL);
}

<STRING>[^\\"\n]+  {
  fprintf(yyout, fmt, "<STRING>[^\\\\\"\\n]+", yytext, yytext);
}
```

Comment: Add an explicit default rule.

Comment: @CV There is nothing unclear about this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pattern for

```
<STRING>\\[\\"]
```

and (in effect) for

```
<STRING>[^\\]
```

But you have no pattern which matches `\` followed by something other than `\` or `"`:

```
<STRING>\\[^\\"]
```

Also, you have no pattern which will match `\` at the very end of the input

```
<STRING>\\
```

Finally, you don't have a pattern which will match EOF if it occurs in the middle of a string

```
<STRING><<EOF>>
```

(`%option nodefault` doesn't care about `<<EOF>>` default rules but you probably will want to issue an error message.)

Unfortunately, flex doesn't (as far as I know) tell you which string might trigger a default action. That feature has been requested a couple of times. However, it's usually pretty easy to see what's missing by just writing the regular expressions for each state one after another in order. (In my experience, the hardest omissions to see are the ones which result from a premature EOF.)

Comment: He also doesn't have a pattern for `<INITIAL>.|\n`, i.e. anything in the initial state that isn't a double quote, which is the real problem.

Comment: @user207421: `<INITIAL>[^"\n]` covers anything that's not a double quote or newline, and there's a newline rule right after it.